# Analytics went to 0 when I switched view to HTTPS

Tags: google-analytics, https

I've had my site and Google Analytics operating on HTTP for years perfectly fine. We recently switched over to HTTPS-only for various and the In-Page Analytics stopped working due to the site being on the "wrong domain."

So I duplicated my `All Website Data` view and changed the new view's websites URL to `https://` leaving everything else the same. The new view shows zero's all around as if there have been no activity on the site. The main view is still working and tracking properly.

Why is the HTTPS view empty? What is the proper way to switch the Google Analytics to HTTPS? Is there another way to get In-Page Analytics working on HTTPS?

**EDIT**
I am using the Google Analyicator WordPress plugin. It renders the following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_addDevId', 'XXXXX']); // Google Analyticator App ID with Google
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://moz.com/community/q/how-does-switching-to-https-effect-google-analytics

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it doesn't address my question.

Comment: Please can you post the Google Analytics tracking code you are using on your website? You may also want to try [this](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/TkNm4yHXd_k/qqmRvv-eimUJ) as well...

Comment: I updated the question with the GA code.